# Modeling block scheduling in optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to figure out the best way to represent block scheduling in optaplanner. The problem is as follows:

- There's a set of employees who need to complete placements working in different jobs. An employee may be in one job for 4 weeks, then a different job for 2 weeks, etc.
- Jobs can last for varying amounts of time, but generally in intervals like 1 week, 2 week, or 4 week 'blocks', each job has its own required length (eg. a 4 week job can't be split up, needs to be completed in a continuous block)
- Usually, 4 week blocks begin at regular intervals. Ex. a 4 week job can start on weeks 1, 4, 8, etc by won't start on weeks 2, 3, 5, etc.
- Each employee has program requirements that say which jobs they need to complete and for how many weeks total
- Every employee should have a job assignment for every 'block', they shouldn't have weeks where they're unassigned

I had some thoughts for how to represent this but I'm not sure what the best way to go about this is. Looking at the design patterns section on assigning time to planning variables, some ways to do this could be:

- Creating a timeslot object for every possible 4 week, 2 week, or 1 week slot. My concern is creating the moves though: a 4 week slot should always be replaced with 4 weeks worth of blocks, I'm not sure if there's a straightforward way to do this with this pattern
- Using a chained through time pattern with a linked list: a linked list could be a good representation, we can easily insert jobs of varying lengths. My main concern is that we know that 4 week blocks only start at certain intervals, so inserting shorter jobs before these 4 week blocks could easily make blocks later in the chain invalid. The chain should also contain a fixed number of weeks, we don't want it to be too short or too long
- Using an array where each element represents a week: ex. a four week job will be placed from indices 0-3 of the array. Now we can place jobs based on which indices they're required to start at. The moves we implement could either: replace a sequence of shorter blocks with one longer block (starting at a valid index), replace a block with one of the same length, or replace a longer block with an equivalent length sequence of shorter blocks, guaranteeing that you're not leaving any weeks empty and preventing blocks from starting in invalid weeks

To me, the last way seems to represent the problem the best. Any advice on the best way to represent this or similar problems I can look into?